# Showing Recent Issues Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode9

I tried many solutions from the web, but neither of them solved my problem. Few weeks ago I left the project working. Today, when I resumed the project, this error started to happen. Could you give me some tip, please?

this is the error in xcode:

```
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted your derived data and rebuild. and it should work fine.
You can access your derived data from the following path 
/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Delete the file and rebuild.

Comment: I did that, but didn't solve. I went to File > Workspace Settings > clicked right Arrow from Derived Data and moved to trash, but didn`t solve

Comment: Are you using cocoapods?

Comment: Try updating your cocopods by running "pod update" in terminal.
Usually it works for me.
if it didn't try updating Xcode.

Comment: No it's okay. as far as you are using swift 3(or objc) and more because Xcode 10 only support swift 3 and grater.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185299/discussion-between-omar-masri-and-marcel).